# Decltype expression type deduction in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to create simple math on c++. I want to use a custom float-point type with epsilon which computes in compile-time. So I need to create type-deduction operations.
And there I have a problem with this code:

```
namespace Math {    
namespace Internal {
    template<typename typeT>
    struct type_value {
        static typeT value_;
    };


template<typename type1T, typename type2T, size_t length>
struct dot_product_type_deducator {
    using value_type =
    decltype(
        (type_value<dot_product_type_deducator<type1T, type2T, length - 1>>::value_)
        + (type_value<dot_product_type_deducator<type1T, type2T, 1>>::value_));
};

template<typename type1T, typename type2T>
struct dot_product_type_deducator<type1T, type2T, 1> {
    using value_type = decltype(type_value<type1T>::value_ * type_value<type2T>::value_);
};
}

template<typename type1T, typename type2T, size_t length>
static auto dot(const Vector<type1T, length> &vector1,
                const Vector<type2T, length> &vector2) {
    return std::inner_product(vector1.begin(), vector1.end(), vector2.begin(),
        static_cast<typename Internal::dot_product_type_deducator<type1T, type2T, length>::value_type>(0));
}

}
```

When I write:

```
dot(Vector<int, 3>{1, 2, 3}, Vector<float, 3>{2, 3, 4})
```

MSVC says:

```
error C2676: binary '+': Math::Internal::dot_product_type_deducator<type1T,type2T,1>' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
1>          with
1>          [
1>              type1T=int,
1>              type2T=float
1>          ]
```

And two more same errors.

**Answer:**

I just forgot to write `dot_product_type_deducator::value_type`.

Comment: Change it to `type_value<typename dot_product_type_deducator<type1T, type2T, length - 1>::value_type>::value_`

Comment: But really you can scrap the code and just do `inner_product(v1.begin(),v1.end(),v2.begin(),common_type_t<type1T,type2T>{0})`

Comment: Can't becouse when I sum more than two floats custom epsilon will be incorrect. for example: I have a vector of 5 `custom_float<epsilon>` and after my operations summing them i will have(for example only(real threeshold should be more)) `custom_float<5 * epsilon>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do this

```
using value_type =
  decltype(
      (type_value<dot_product_type_deducator<type1T, type2T, length - 1>>::value_)
      + (type_value<dot_product_type_deducator<type1T, type2T, 1>>::value_));
```

You're setting `value_type` to be the type you specified. Now, `type_value<...>::value` looks very similar to `std::declval`, which means your `value_type` will be equal to the result of `dot_product_type_deducator` added to itself with `operator+`. But we can clearly see the `dot_product_type_deducator` struct and we can see that it does not have an `operator+` defined on it, hence the error.

I don't know what you're trying to do exactly with these structs, but if you want your code to compile you need to have an `operator+` defined on `dot_product_type_deducator`.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I didnt find in STL `std::declval`. And I fogot to write `dot_product_type_deducator::value_type`